# error in installation of ejabberd

Tags: centos, ejabberd

i am trying to install ejabberd in centos . ejabberd is running but when iam try to register it showing error like this.

```
/opt/ejabberd-14.12/bin/ejabberdctl register root testrecoveryim.test-mobile.com test
The node 'ejabberd@test' is started with status: started
ejabberd is not running in that node
Check for error messages: /opt/ejabberd-14.12/logs/ejabberd.log
or other files in that directory.

Error in ejabberd ctl process: 'error' badarg

Commands to start an ejabberd node:
  start  Start an ejabberd node in server mode
  debug  Attach an interactive Erlang shell to a running ejabberd node
  live   Start an ejabberd node in live (interactive) mode

Optional parameters when starting an ejabberd node:
  --config-dir dir   Config ejabberd:    /opt/ejabberd-14.12/conf
  --config file      Config ejabberd:    /opt/ejabberd-14.12/conf/ejabberd.yml
  --ctl-config file  Config ejabberdctl: /opt/ejabberd-14.12/conf/ejabberdctl.cfg
  --logs dir         Directory for logs: /opt/ejabberd-14.12/logs
  --spool dir        Database spool dir: /opt/ejabberd-14.12/database/ejabberd@dummy-OKRestore2
  --node nodename    ejabberd node name: ejabberd@test
```

and the ejabberd log is

```
2016-04-29 17:44:34.196 [error] <0.37.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.37.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {undefined_macro,''} in application_master:init/4 line 133
2016-04-29 17:44:34.196 [info] <0.7.0> Application ejabberd exited with reason: {undefined_macro,''}
```

Comment: Installer and code have been much improved in two years and a half. Why don't you try with ejabberd 16.04 ?